# xmllint with html entities in XPath

Tags: xpath, xmllint

I'm trying to use xmllint to parse different values out of an XML.

The tags look like this:

```
<attribute name="Fel&#xFC;letkezel&#xE9;" value="Painted /Festett/" />
```

I'm using the following XPath with xmllint and all I get is `XPath set is empty`:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(xml/transactions/transaction/document/configuration/attribute[@name="Fel&#xFC;letkezel&#xE9;s"]/@value)'
```

I'm expecting it to return "Painted /Festett/". I've tried escaping the semicolons.

Using `recode` or `xmlstarlet` is not an option.

How can I get the value of the tag with html entities in XPath?

Comment: The cause of this error is merely a typo: remove the trailing `s` of the XPath's predicate expression. `'string(xml/transactions/transaction/document/configuration/attribute[@name="Fel&#xFC;letkezel&#xE9;"]/@value)'` does work fine.